# Can't debug t-sql statement - could not connect to computer '.'

Tags: sql-server, debugging

When I was about to debug a T-SQL select statement, an error dialog popped up:

> Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer '.'. This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

How can I start debugging?

Comment: Has it worked successfully in the past? Could it be related to configuration? Have you checked MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646008(v=sql.105)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You must connect to Management Studio with a server name rather than `.` or `(local)`.

`localhost` also works.

Comment: M$ is one of the rare companies that is able to make me this annoyed with its lack of such undocummented glitches.

Comment: Magic answer. Thanks.